# Is it dangerous to put pdf files with cryptographically-generated-128-character file names in a public web folder?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, security, iis, webserver

I have a site that allow the user to request a secret report in a pdf format.

My idea is to put the generated pdf files in a public folder with disabled directory browsing.

Each file name consists of 128 characters that are uniquely and cryptographically generated.

The legitimate user will be given the link of his/her own report.

Is it dangerous to put pdf files with cryptographically-generated-128-character file names in a public web folder?

Comment: 'Dangerous' in what sense? You have [capabilities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capability-based_security) here, which is nice, but there's no control on passing the capabilities to someone else. Do you need to trust your users to not share the URLs? Do _they_ need to trust that someone else won't share their URLs? Facebook and similar sites often don't perform any access control on image URLs, so it is easy to pass along URLs of compromising photos to unauthorized people, and photo owner can only delete the photo to combat it. If they had used ACLs as well, this wouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well it does qualify as **security-through-obscurity**, so it's frowned upon. Think about following scenario's:

- What happens when someone else gets **a hold of the link**? By snooping the connection, reading e-mails, hacking a computer which contains a bookmark/download history/cache. Since the link is always there, your document is now public.
- If at any time in the future, a minor part of your server is compromised and the directory is indexed, even for a second, all files are public. This can be one badly-written script, one injection, one XSS-vulnerability, one currently unknown zero-day. You are exposing your documents to the **weakest link**.

**You should probably not do this**. Instead, keep the documents at a **secure location**, out of the document-root. Then when an authenticated user asks for the document over a secure (HTTPS) connection, **serve the document using a script** that reads the document and writes it over the connection. No temporary files in the documentroot!

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply enable download from your script?

download.php?file=128_char_filename.pdf

Where download.php checks the users permission for that file. That way you would not have "secure" pdf files in a public folder.

Forcing a file download with ASP.NET: http://www.haiders.net/post/Force-File-Download-with-ASPNET.aspx

Comment: In your scenario, the pdf files are already generated or they will be generated on the fly when the authenticated request comes?

Comment: This example assumes your files are already generated. But you can generate the file on the fly and then feed it to the browser for download. Just replace WriteFile with something more appropriate.